# How to create a html select drop down list from a text file

Tags: javascript, html, express-handlebars

I have a text file that looks like this:
fruit,size,color

I want to be able to load the text file and create a dynamic select drop down list from it.

This is my code for now, it is not working. it is not printing anything in the browser console, also nothing is in the select drop downn list. Could some one advise what I did wrong?

Below is the code, I use handle bar to render the page to users.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>


 <head>
   <form method="post" action="index/display" id = "first" name="first">
  <title>AUTOSELECTEST</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
      $.get(js/pytxt.txt",
      function(data) {

        alert( "Data Loaded: " );
        console.log('start processing text')
        console.log(data); /* Open the console too see the data */
        var options = data.split(','),
          /* Something to "explode" by. See link. */
          $select = $('select#value');
          for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
          $select.append('<option value="' + i + '">' + options[i] + '</option>"');
        console.log ($select)
      });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page-wrap">
    <h1>Pulls from text files</h1>
    <select id="value">
                <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
            </select>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the json that you are using, and also you can remove the code that is irrelevant to the question (e.g. the icon, stylesheet etc.) Please see how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: From the JSON above, what are the expected options to be loaded in `select` ?

Comment: so JSON file looks like this: { "fruit": "Apple", "size": "Large", "color": "Red" }, the expected options to be loaded in select is fruit, size, color, and when user select fruit, the value is apple that gets selected, when user select size, large gets selected as value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have debugged the code, Please try below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>


 <head>
  <title>AUTOSELECTEST</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
        $.get(/public/js/pytxt.json",
              function(data,error) {
                if (error) {
                      console.log (error);
                  }
                alert( "Data Loaded: " );
                console.log('start processing text')
                console.log(data); /* Open the console too see the data */
                var options = JSON.parse(data);
                /* Something to "explode" by. See link. */
                for (i in options) {
                  $("#value").append('<option value="' + options[i] + '">' + i + '</option>');
                }
      });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page-wrap">
    <h1>Pulls from text files</h1>
    <select id="value">
                <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
            </select>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. it works. I can see the content of the file in the select drop downlist now. however, when I output user selected value, it shows "0 or 1 or 2 or 3" , I think its not capturing the value instead output the position of the select array. what should I do?

Comment: You should use `$(#value).val()` to get the selected value.

Comment: I just tried, its clearly taking the value as "Apple" when "Fruit" is selected. Can you show the code, how you get output from it?

Comment: Use `<select id="value" onchange="console.log(this.value);">`. will print selected value in console.

Comment: actually, I literally copy and past your code into autoselect.hbs file and when I hit that page: there is nothing in the select drop down , and in the browser console, I got this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (autoselect:18)
    at c (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at l (jquery.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:2)

Comment: This error says, json file content from server is not in proper Json format. Please check server response.

Comment: I have triple checked my json file using json lint and it looks right.

Comment: so instead of using json, I will just read a text. I have edited the code. when i select the drop down, I do see fruit, size, color. now when I click submit, it is printing out 0 , 1 or 2 instead of the value. could you please advise how to capture the actual value?

Comment: @jia chang As you have got answer for what you asked, in this question, I suggest you to post that as a new question, instead of growing comment thread.

Comment: do i need to close this question so you can get credit? @Liju?

Comment: If you find my answer useful, pleade click the green check mark in my answer. No need to close.

Comment: done. also posted new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63494611/capture-selected-item-value-from-a-select-drop-down-list-created-from-a-text-fil