# capture selected item value from a select drop down list created from a text file using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, handlebars.js

I have a text file that contains a few simple words like: make, this, work.

I want to be able to load the text file and create a dynamic select drop down list from it. When the user clicks submit, it prints out the value of selected item.

Below is the code, I use handle bar to render the page to users. When the user clicks on the submit button, it goes to index/display to see what they selected.

Instead of printing out the actual value of selected options, it prints out index of the selected option, not the value.

```html
<form method="post" action="index/display" id = "first" name="first">
<fieldset>
   <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left:10px ">
      <legend>Selecting items from text file</legend>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script>
         $.get("js/pytxt.txt",
           function(data) {
               /*alert( "Data Loaded: " );*/
               var options = data.split(','),
               $select = $('select#value');
               for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                   $select.append('<option value="' + i + '">' + options[i] + '</option>"');
                   console.log ($select)};
         });
      </script>
      <p>
         <label></label>
         <select id = "value" name="first">
            <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
         </select>
      </p>
   </div>
   <p>
      <input type="submit">
   </p>
</fieldset>
```

This is the post function:

```js
app.post('/index/display', (req, res) => {
   res.status(200).send('POST works!' + req.body.first);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace:

```js
$select.append('<option value="' + i + '">' + options[i] + '</option>"');
```

With this line:

```js
$select.append('<option value="' + options[i] + '">' + options[i] + '</option>"');
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: @jiachang Because you are using i (which is the index) as the value of instead of getting the value at index i from options.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this a bit doing:

```
options.forEach(v => $select.append( new Option(v, v)))
```

---

Demo:

```js
let options = 'one,two,three,four'.split(','), $select = $('#value');

options.forEach(v => $select.append( new Option(v, v)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="value"></select>
```